# How to check if my Live-Wallpaper is running

Tags: java, android, live-wallpaper

I have a Live Wallpaper and an Activity. How can I check in the Activity if the User activated my Wallpaper and how can I send him to the Live Wallpaper Settings if not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution:

1. Method for checking if Service is running

   ```
   private boolean isMyServiceRunning(String className) {
   ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
   for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
       if (className.equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
           return true;
       }
   }
   return false;}
   ```
2. Start Intent ACTION_SET_WALLPAPER

   ```
       //Check if Wallpaper Service is active
   if(isMyServiceRunning(MyWallpaperService.class.getName())){
       Log.d(TAG, "active" );
   } else {
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SET_WALLPAPER);
       startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getActivity().getString(R.string.title_for_wallpaper_chooser)));
   }
   ```